# How to change order in which the components are processed

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a `selectOneMenu` and an `editor`. What I want is to submit the value of the `editor` before the value of the `selectOneMenu`. The code looks like this

```
<p:selectOneMenu value="#{myBB.selectedItem}">
  <f:selectItems value="#{myBB.selectItems}"/>
  <p:ajax event="change" process="itemText @this" update=":mainForm"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>

<p:editor id="itemText" value="#{myBB.selectedItem.text}"/>
```

It looks like the order of elements in `process="itemText @this"` doesn't matter, because when I change it, the values are submitted in unchanged order.

The problem is, that the `selectedItem` of the editor is changed by the selection before the value from the editor is submitted.

Am I right, that the order doesn't matter and it is submitted based on the order in the DOM tree? (When I change order of the input fields it's working as I would like to)
What is the best way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't rely on things like layout or processing order in your code. If the problem is that `itemText` value is reset when `selectedItem` is changed, then bind the text to separate `String text` bean variable, and update `selectedItem.text` in some other code, maybe `<p:ajax listener="#{...}"`.

Comment: p:editor doesn't support ajax. I found a way to do that via remotecommand, but I have bad expirence with it. In the end, I decided to create multiple editors in the tabview(i needed just 4 options) and now it's even more comprehensive i guess. Anyway thanks for help

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I meant ajax listener in `selectOneMenu`, the one you already have. Anyway, glad you got it working.